# better identification of the child

Tags: c, linux, process, child-process, zombie-process

I tried to create a zombie process, using the `ps` command for verification. Although the solution is good, it is not very suggestive for identifying the child as a zombie. Can anyone help me with some improvements?

this is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int pid=fork();
   if (pid>0)
   {
       printf("in parent process");
       sleep(30);
       execlp("ps","ps",NULL);
   }
   else if (pid==0) 
   {
       printf("in child process");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. I see `<defunct>` after `a.out`. By the way, `sleep(30)` is way overkill. Just `sleep(1)` is more than enough time. (And you could even do `waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOWAIT);` to replace `sleep` entirely and it will still work.)

Comment: And what do you want for a _good enough_ solution to be _more suggestive_ ?  Isn't that some subjective way of talking?  Do you want something or just _something_?  A Zombie process is a dead process... there's no resources allocated for it in the system, but just a process table's entry.

Answer (score 0):

A Zombie process doesn't represent anything but a dead process for which it's parent has not already `wait(2)`ed.  It's existence is just to provide the kernel a means to pass back to it's parent process it's accounting details (like cpu time spent, or exit code) in order to make the `wait(2)` system call reliable.

There's nothing else, depending on the operating system, you cannot even get the command line parameters used to call it, or the name of the process that it represents.

The only thing you can do with a zombie process is for its parent to `wait(2)` for it, and so, pass up the accounting details, exit code and other info upto its parent.  No memory is assigned to it, no system resources are dedicated or locked, all its file descriptors are already closed, only it's pid, process-group id, session-id, and accumulated system and user space cpu times (for it, and the accumulated of its children) is stored in the process table, so the `wait(2)` system call can also accumulate them when the parent process `exit(2)`s or `wait(2)`s for it.

As you'll probably have already detected, you cannot `kill(2)` a zombie process (well, you can indeed `kill(2)` its parent, so it will rest in peace forever ---and the parent) as it is already dead.

In order to get a better identification of the process, you have to gather that info in the parent process (the parent receives all of it in the `wait(2)` family of system calls)  You'll get the `pid_t` process id, so you'll know which of your child processes is the one you have `wait(2)`ed for.  As you (the parent) created it, you'll know everything you need to know your children (you got this pid from the `fork(2)` system call when you created it)